# Add labeldrop to all prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus

I'm using the prometheus-kube-stack on Kubernetes.

I want to remove all `prometheus_replica` and `prometheus` labels from all metrics. To do this I have to add the following configuration to every scrape job:

```
- regex: (prometheus_replica|prometheus)
  action: labeldrop
```

It seems like there isn't any global `labeldrop` option, and I need to add to any scrape job instead. Is there a way to globally apply this setting?

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove **prometheus_replica** and **prometheus** labels from all metrics , you need to set the fields **replicaExternalLabelName** and **prometheusExternalLabelName** to empty strings in the Prometheus cluster accordingly.

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/ca400fdc3edd0af0df896a338eca270e115b74d7/Documentation/api.md#prometheusspec) in github, the mentioned fields provide the below information.

> **replicaExternalLabelName** :
>
> Name of Prometheus external label used to denote replica name.
> Defaults to the value of **prometheus_replica**. External label will not
> be added when value is set to empty string ("").
>
> **prometheusExternalLabelName** :
>
> Name of Prometheus external label used to denote Prometheus instance
> name. Defaults to the value of **prometheus**. External label will not be
> added when value is set to empty string ("").

Hope the above information helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
For both of them you are right and sorry for not being clear enough.
I picked these two randomly, I meant how can I do that for other labels like env or id, if I want to remove them.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Can you check the below article by Tanmay Bhat and let me know if it is useful in resolving this issue.
https://faun.pub/how-to-drop-and-delete-metrics-in-prometheus-7f5e6911fb33

Comment: Thanks, but it won't help, since I'm looking for a global change instead of changing every job

Comment: Can you check if the "labelkeep" action can be used as an option which keeps a specific set of labels and drop everything else. Refer to the link for more information.
https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/#labelkeeplabeldrop

Comment: @yershalom Can you please confirm if the above reference is useful to you.

Comment: It didn't help since it is also on job level.

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting the same thing; currently, from what I was told on Slack, there is no Global method, which is pretty crappy!

So I have had to add relabeling to everything in and out of the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.